# Why _.clone() doesn't copy object methods?

Tags: angular, underscore.js

I use the underscore library to copy objects, the _.clone() method. And this method works differently on different versions of angular, or maybe the problem is something else?

F.e:

```
class FooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    
    constructor(foo: string, bar: number) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    
    toString() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
...
const foo = new FooBar("fooBar", null);
const bar = _.clone(foo);
console.log(bar); // Angular v12 output: {foo: "fooBar", bar: ƒ}, Angular v13 output: {foo: "fooBar"}
```

Why wasn't the method copied?

[Dependencies before/after "ng update"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUa2h.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.

Comment: `_.clone` should be used with plain objects. `foo` is not a plain object. https://underscorejs.org/#clone